# Windows Workflow 4 slow running in development

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

We have an issue where Windows Workflow in VS 2010 is running slow in development. When debugging it takes up to 10 secs before it hits the breakpoint in WF. The rest of the infrastructure is fine. i.e. UI and Service layer debugging is fast. 
Our xaml is simple but contains a lot of different cases so is 284kb. Editing it is generally OK.

I'm happy that it takes a while to load the xaml when debugging. However when I remove the debug point I expect it to run fast again. This is not happening. I have other xamls of a similar size which have never had debug points set in them and they run fast. As soon as I add a debug point, even though I later remove it, it runs unbelievably slow.

I am part of a development team and I have a slow running Master.xaml and a teammate has a slow running GeneralLedger.xaml. As these are different it can't be part of the common code which is checked in.

We have checked the project properties and rebuilt the solution.suo file, but nothing appears to be helping.

Any ideas?

Comment: Answer your own question posting another answer bellow.

Comment: Uh, I think @Davi was saying that you should add your answer below rather than in the body of your question.  It may seem odd, but that's how we do it here.  After the required waiting period, you can select it as correct.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I was going to do that but had to wait 8 hours before I could answer my own question. I'll do it shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, but hopefully it'll help someone else.

After checking the output when running the solution we found the following line for the xamls which didn't have performance problems.

Instrumentation for debugger fails.  Reason: Could not find file 'D:\AProject\MasterOrchestration\Master.xamlx'..The thread '' (0x2dcc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

As my colleague and I had our code on different drives it couldn't load the XamlDebugger for the projects which the other had put a debug point in (as they didn't exist on the other machine). This lead us to find the element below in the Master.xaml file.

Removing the entire element fixed the speed issue and the app is running fast again.

```
sad:XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName="C:\AProject\MasterOrchestration\Master.xamlx"
```

Comment: Also note that you may not be able to debug the XAML if the debug path above (XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName) does not match the Xaml location on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you need that file name to debug your workflow. Using the same directory structure is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks Maurice. My main issue is that it was running like a dog when I wasn't debugging. I needed to remove that line to improve the non-debugging performance. 
Also when you put a debug point in it automatically adds the line to  the xaml.